# Add a module or create a separate project?

Tags: java, maven

I am in need of separate jar of some classes existing in a multi-module project. I need to pull those classes out of existing module so that I can create a jar for them which I can then export to some other project. What I am thinking is what's the advantage of creating separate module in existing project or altogether creating a separate project?
I can't think of possible trade-off. Can you tell me the trade offs involved.

Comment: Although I think this is a good question, it might currently be too broad. One may also need to consider version control, deployment and development /dev ops processes.

Comment: I would think on the dependencies and the life cycle of the modules. So does your shared jar depend on other modules, or do other modules depend on a current version of the shared jar? There is some danger in having shared jars too close to the other modules, as one often puts too much code into there. Another aspect would be: what is the release cycle of the shared jar? is it the same as the other modules? Or is it done, tested, released, left like that? Then a separate project would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create an another module instead of a separate project.

Justification:
1) You can pack this jar and use wherever you want it.
2) You can add this module as a dependency to the other modules
3) We will be following the the Maven general rule "one primary artifact per POM"

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you should only create a new project if the set of classes you're moving are coherently useful. If this new project you're going to create can be used to solve a problem (with a good API), I think it's a good enough reason to create a new project.

Otherwise, it's perfectly fine for a maven artifact to be shared among other projects even it is just a module of a multi-module project.

Just my $0.02

Answer (score 0):

module: 
 - easy to manage dependencies 
 - easy to support shared components. For example two modules use the same
 database. 
 - build/ci process may take longer 
project:
  - you can easily deploy projects separately with their own versions and so on 
  - more convinient in case a dedicated team works on a seprated project 
  - easy to manage build system 
  - more complicated to handle dependencies